# Trying to install Steam, getting "Package 'steam:i386' has no installation candidate" error

Tags: package-management, software-installation, steam

As you can read in the title..

$ sudo apt install steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package steam:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another
 package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'steam:i386' has no installation candidate

On a sidenote, I ALWAYS get errors on Ubuntu nowadays when I try to install stuff. I can't install through the Software Center either - nothing happens when I'm clicking the Install button!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment so I'm posting an answer :

Please try to use apt-get.
First, add the repository multiverse : `sudo add-apt-repository multiverse`
Second, install : `sudo apt-get install steam`

EDIT : If you have error message about i386, then you should run :

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have already tried that but it doesn't solve the problem. I still get the same Error message even tho it says "'multiverse' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.".